# Plank magnifying effect

Tags: plank

I swear there is a way to make the icons magnify like on a mac osx when you mouse hovers over them (I don't know what I did but i had this effect until recently I updated plank and it's gone).

I am currently on a Elementary OS Freya

Comment: The magnify effect looks so ugly, it looks like some old cheap animation...

Comment: @JulianLai Try to keep comments constructive and critical, opinions are better served in chat.

Comment: Sorry - not much of an answer, but doesn't one of the docks in the Appcener - Cairo or Docky do this?

Answer (score 20):

elementary is unable to ship a version of Plank with this code because of the Apple software patents. The version we ship has the feature patched out to avoid litigation.

You can get the upstream version of Plank from [Rico's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ricotz/+archive/ubuntu/docky)

Comment: isn't magnifying just zoom? and isn't that enabled in `~/.config/plank/dock1/settings` with `#Whether the dock will zoom when hovered.
ZoomEnabled=true`?

Comment: @cipricus I just confirmed with Rico that the feature is not present in Freya, but also that the patch hasn't yet been applied in Loki. In other words, you're not using a released version of elementary OS if this setting is present and working for you.

Comment: I must have had some problems with sources and cleaned all the PPAs, while this build of Plank was already installed :)

Comment: Is there any way I can enable the magnifying effect in loki 0.4.1?

Comment: Thanks for that! Do you have any specific information of the patents involved? Mac OS X is more than 20 years old, so it’s very likely they are lapsed.

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/docky
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall plank
killall plank
plank --preferences
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it's better if you actually say what these commands do.

Comment: It's Rico's PPA mentioned by Daniel Foré in [his answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/1934/170)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: @ophius your method did it well but when I close the preferences the dock will automatically disappear

Comment: this no longer works because the standard version number is higher. needs a rebuild. Fails on Juno/Hera. Still works on Loki

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need indeed the build provided by the PPA mentioned in the main answer. After that it is simple to `make the icons magnify [...] when your mouse hovers over them`

[image]

```
gedit ~/.config/plank/dock1/settings
```

Change like so:

```
#Whether the dock will zoom when hovered. 
ZoomEnabled=true
```

The zoom level is set here:

```
#The dock's icon-zoom (in percent).
ZoomPercent=150
```

---

I see this when I check Synaptic:

[image]

Comment: Manjaro OS doesn't have this feature. Ophius's answer worked for me.

Comment: @PrajwalDhatwalia - this site and all posts here cover exclusevely elementary OS. If you are looking for posts concerning Manjaro on stackexhange, try https://unix.stackexchange.com/