# How to change or replace the dock?

Tags: plank

Is it possible to change the appearance of the dock or to replace it with a different one like Docky? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

There is a settings menu for the plank, but it is very limited. You can find it by right clicking on the plank, but you need to make sure you aren't clicking on an icon. This can prove quite tricky.

To replace the plank:

1. First, disable plank, this can be done using any configuration tool editor. Install the editor if you don't already have one:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
   ```
2. Once installed, open the editor and select:

   - Under 0.4 loki:

     ```
     org -> pantheon -> desktop -> cerbere`
     ```
   - Under other versions:

     ```
     org -> pantheon -> cerbere
     ```
3. Under *monitored processes* you'll see something like `[‘wingpanel’, ‘plank’, ‘slingshot-launcher –silent’]`, simply remove `plank`.
4. Reboot your device, the plank should now be gone.
5. Install Docky, or the dock of your choice. For Docky:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install docky
   ```
6. You can now remove plank if you wish (not necessary):

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove plank
   ```
7. Finally you need to set the new dock to run on startup, this is usually done in the docks settings panel. For Docky ensure that the 'Start When User Logs In' is checked.

If you wish to reinstall plank, make sure you remove the other dock first, and that you add 'plank' back to the config file.

Also, it should be noted that all installations can be done through the software center if you don't want to use the command line.

For your convenience here's a [link](http://techdissected.com/web-and-computing/linux/elementary-os-stock-app-dock-doesnt-rock-lets-change-it/) to a tutorial explaining this in a bit more detail. [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203803/replace-plank-with-docky-in-elementary-os) is another example of how to replace plank on the stack exchange.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Also, please avoid using lmgtfy in answers. It's potentially as rude as saying "Did you _google_ before asking your question?" It is generally assumed that users come here when they can't find the answer on Google.

Comment: @RolandiXor Thanks for the tips, was first time answering a question. Will be generally better in future.

Comment: There's no Cerbere option at dconf editor below pantheon.

Answer (score 5):

### To change the appearnce

According to [this Daniel Foré's answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/1934/170) Freya uses a Plank version that has some options patched out.

To get more changes one should use [Rico's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ricotz/+archive/ubuntu/docky) and install from there (after uninstalling the default version).

Then, to change the appearance of the dock (Plank) one can use themes that can be found on the net,  e.g. on [deviantart.](http://www.deviantart.com/browse/all/customization/skins/linuxutil/applications/docks/?q=plank)

[image]

Themes are located in `~/.local/share/plank/themes` and `/usr/share/plank/themes`.

The settings can be accessed by right-clicking the dock (a bit tricky, you have to do that outside any icon) or by the command `plank --preferences`.

[image]

To find that in the application launcher for the future (using `gedit` text editor):

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/plank_preferences.desktop
```

and paste this & save:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Plank Settings
Exec=plank --preferences
Icon=plank
Terminal=false
Categories=GNOME;GTK;System;
X-GNOME-Keywords=Center;Control;Panel;Preferences;System;
X-AppInstall-Keywords=Center;Control;Panel;Preferences;System;
X-GNOME-Gettext-Domain=switchboard
Actions=AboutDialog;
```

Also one can install elementary-tweaks.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks
```

[image]

To manually change settings, edit `~/.config/plank/dock1/settings` which contains detailed description of the possible options. Mine looks like so:

```
#This file auto-generated by Plank.
#2016-05-02T07:00:48+0000

[PlankDockPreferences]
#Whether to show only windows of the current workspace.
CurrentWorkspaceOnly=false
#The size of dock icons (in pixels).
IconSize=30
#If 0, the dock won't hide.  If 1, the dock intelligently hides.  If 2, the dock auto-hides. If 3, the dock dodges active maximized windows. If 4, the dock dodges every window.
HideMode=0
#Time (in ms) to wait before unhiding the dock.
UnhideDelay=0
#Time (in ms) to wait before hiding the dock.
HideDelay=0
#The plug-name of the monitor for the dock to show on (e.g. DVI-I-1, HDMI1, LVDS1). Leave this empty to keep on the primary monitor.
Monitor=
#List of *.dockitem files on this dock. DO NOT MODIFY
DockItems=pantheon-files.dockitem;;seamonkey.dockitem;;firefox.dockitem;;deadbeef.dockitem;;clementine.dockitem;;SoundWire-Server.dockitem;;pavucontrol.dockitem;;Players.dockitem;;RADIOS.dockitem;;Enable.dockitem;;audacious_cd.dockitem
#The position for the dock on the monitor.  If 0, left.  If 1, right.  If 2, top.  If 3, bottom.
Position=3
#The dock's position offset from center (in percent).
Offset=0
#The name of the dock's theme to use.
Theme=Kit-Kat
#The alignment for the dock on the monitor's edge.  If 0, panel-mode.  If 1, left-aligned.  If 2, right-aligned.  If 3, centered.
Alignment=3
#The alignment of the items in this dock if panel-mode is used.  If 1, left-aligned.  If 2, right-aligned.  If 3, centered.
ItemsAlignment=3
#Whether to prevent drag'n'drop actions and lock items on the dock.
LockItems=false
#Whether to use pressure-based revealing of the dock if the support is available.
PressureReveal=true
#Whether to show only pinned applications. Useful for running more then one dock.
PinnedOnly=false
#Whether to automatically pin an application if it seems useful to do.
AutoPinning=true
#Whether to show the item for the dock itself.
ShowDockItem=false
#Whether the dock will zoom when hovered.
ZoomEnabled=true
#The dock's icon-zoom (in percent).
ZoomPercent=103
```

---

### To replace the Dock

Nothing stops you.
Plank can be uninstalled or just disabled as indicated in the other answer (also [here)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/184752/32012)  and a different dock can be installed.

(**I see Plank as part  of the whole concept of elementary OS**. When such ideas come in my mind I think it's better to use a different system than start disassembling one that was conceived in the way elementary is.)

Comment: This **does not** answer *the question*, no matter how well written.

Comment: @RolandiXor - Thanks for commenting, but I really don't get what you mean. *the question* has two parts: **1. change appearance of the dock** (my answer: `use Plank themes`, `use tweaks or Plank preferences` providing the command for the latter and a desktop file to launch the GUI of that, which is not present  by default,  and edit `~/.config/plank/dock1/settings`), **2. is it possible to replace with Docky** (my answer: `yes`, link to other answer, suggesting it doesn't make much sense to do it though).

Comment: @RolandiXor - I had forgotten that I'm not using the default Plank version but the one from  [Rico's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ricotz/+archive/ubuntu/docky). I have added that to the answer now and made the two parts of the answer more clear.

Comment: @RolandiXor - I really appreciate your posts (they helped me in the past) so I dislike having negative comments from you: would you please take again a look at my edited answer and give me some feedback on how to improve it or even to remove it?

Comment: Much better now :)

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding - somehow I must have misread the question. I'm almost certain I remember the question being a bit different before... oh well - all on me.

Comment: @RolandiXor - not the question but the answer was different: the two parts of the answer were not as clear as they are now. also, in the first version I had omitted the fact that a PPA was needed to have the non-restricted version of Plank.