# Plank on Elementary OS doesn't zoom

Tags: plank

I want to add a magnyfying effect on plank on elementary os. I've looked into a lot of forum and try what they propose (change the settings file, uninstall and reinstall,...) but that doesn't work. Plank do not zoom.

Have you any idea why it doesnt work ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

looks like elementary OS team can't ship plank with this effect due to some kind of conflict with apple's patents.

You can try to install plank from Rico's ppa; the version in this ppa should include the magnifying effect, as explained [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1933/plank-magnifying-effect)